# iOS CallKit Configurations in Detail

Tags: ios, twilio, webrtc, voip, callkit

I'm using CallKit to connect Twilio RTC and I'd like to know more about CallKit.

There is a timer in the lock screen of the CallKit and I am trying to start the timer after I receive response from the server. Right now the timer would just start counting right after the "connecting" phase, in which my response haven't even started yet.

1. It seems like starting after calling [action fulfill], but how should I implement with the http call? or Twilio function?

If I'm calling from the call history of the native call app made by Apple, where should I store the  mapping information for UUID to the user-id I'd like to call?

2. I know that the callee can save these information in CXUpdate and show without problem, but how about the caller? I can't tell from the examples of saving call information in CXHandle.

Thanks ahead for reading through :)

Answer (score 0):

Intiate call timer after call connecting state to connected

```
var callTimer: Timer?
var timeDuration: TimeInterval = 0.0
//MARK:- CallTimer
    func initiateCallTimer() {
        if callTimer == nil {
            self.callTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: kRefreshTimeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(CallViewController.refreshCallTimer(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

func callTimerInvalidate() {
    if callTimer != nil {
        callTimer?.invalidate()
        callTimer = nil
    }
}

@objc func refreshCallTimer(_ sender: Timer) {
    timeDuration += kRefreshTimeInterval
    print(timeDuration)
    self.lblConnectiong.text = string(withTimeDuration: timeDuration)
}

func string(withTimeDuration timeDuration: TimeInterval) -> String? {
    let minutes = Int(timeDuration / 60)
    let seconds = Int(timeDuration) % 60
    let timeStr = String(format: "%ld:%02ld", minutes, seconds)
    return timeStr
}
```

and invalidate after rejected or end

```
self.callTimerInvalidate()
```

for this call from  recent call list

In your app's Info.plist, you must have INStartAudioCallIntent and/or INStartVideoCallIntent in the NSUserActivityTypes key, and your app delegate must implement the -application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler: method to handle the start call intent.

Comment: Thanks for the instant reply! We're now trying the method you provided. As for the timer I mentioned in the first part, it's the native screen provided by Apple CallKit. We're not able to start it after connecting successfully with Twilio, which could be very confusing for the user. The duration will be exaggerated because it starts before the connection is established.